# wcf crashes in one pc and in the development pc runs perfectly

Tags: c#, wcf

hi implementing an wcf service that executes scripts (C# code) saved in a specific folder.
but i have a problem it crashes in all pcs except the pc that im developing in all are the same edition of win7 . How ican see why it's crashing ?

the WCf service is hosted in a windows service

Comment: Please provide some detail. "it crashes" tells us nothing.

Comment: There could be any number of reasons - missing dependencies, folder permissions, ...

Comment: What is the exception and where does it come from (stack trace)?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Event Viewer, both in the Application and System sections. That might give you some clues.

Also, security is a possibility since it only runs on the dev machine.  But I'd start with the events.

Comment: iin the event log under applications it shows:
Name faulty implementation ScrablerServiceHost.exe, version 1.0.0.0, time stamp 0x4c0e5f84
Name faulty module clr.dll, version 4.0.30319.1, time stamp 0x4ba21eeb
Code exception: 0xc00000fd
Offset error: 0x0000000000004be7
Faulty process ID: 0x1128
Time of application defects: 0x01cb0767e0795100
Document defective application: C: \ Program Files (x86) \ Paris Koutsioukis \ Scrabler Service \ ScrablerServiceHost.exe
Document ellatomatikis module: C: \ Windows \ Microsoft.NET \ Framework64 \ v4.0.30319 \ clr.dll

Comment: i translate it with google translate , because i use the greek version of win7

Comment: A! im runing under the NetworkService Account iwant to accept connections from lan , idont know what happens if i use localsystem account